# How do i use a Resources.resx in a C# class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i am currently using this line of code

```
resourceManager = new ResourceManager("Namespace.class", GetType().Assembly);
```

to try use a resourse but keep getting a error:
 System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException was unhandled
i am just trying to use the default .resx file made by VS2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ResXFileCodeGeneratorEx.aspx

You don't need to initiate your own ResourceManager, as Visual Studio ResXFileCodeGenerator already does that for you.

Answer (score 2):

The class is created using static members.

Usually, you reference it like this:

```
Resources.ResourceClassName.ResourceName
```

Check the xxx.designer.cs file to know the namespace and class name to use.